# Connection and Session Pooling in Jboss EAP 6.2 server to connect to MQ

Tags: java, jboss

I want to implement Connection and Session pooling in jboss-eap-6.2 server to improve the transaction rate. As of now application has to open and close connection each time while sending the message to MQ. Please let me know what should be the configuration in jboss server.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your data sources there is a pool tag that you can use in the standalone config file

```
    <datasources>
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jndiname" pool-name="Datasourcepoolname" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>//connection_string</connection-url>
            <driver>MYSQL</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>125</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>false</prefill>
                <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
            </pool>
            <timeout>
                <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
            </timeout>
        </datasource>
    <datasources>
```

Here is more on JBoss Datasource configuration:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration